# Nginx don't redirect to vue 404 page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx

I have a Vue SPA, in my localhost when I start project by npm run serve and try to access a route that I have not defined takes me to 404, this is my vue router configuration

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'MainLayout',
    component: () => import('../layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    meta: {
        middleware: 'translation'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'Index',
            component: () => import('@/application/views/Index.vue')
        },
       // other routes
        {
            path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
            component: import('@/application/views/404Page.vue'),
            name: 'NotFound'
        }
    ]
},
```

In my server that I use nginx with this configuration it does not but I can see <Header> or <Footer> components that are defined in my MainLayout

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

MainLayout.vue

```
  <div class='w-full min-h-screen'>
    <Header class="flex-shrink-0"/>
    <router-view class="flex-grow"/>
    <Footer class="flex-shrink-0"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried this configuration in my nginx conf file but doesn't work

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/application_error.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on this line:

```
component: import('@/application/views/404Page.vue')
```

It should be like this:

```
component: () => import('@/application/views/404Page.vue')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between frontend routing (vue-router) or backend routing (nginx).

With your config Nginx will redirect everything to index.html at first hit.

Then you use a frontend router with a catchAll route so routing is done entirely inside your browser. Nginx will never be queried after that first hit.

If you want nginx to handle the 404 you have to remove the catchAll from your frontend routing (but it would be useless as 404 is again using index.html).